# Boolean operation BUG?

Tags: modifiers

I can not properly cut out holes with boolean modifier. Difference or Union looks very similar. The object with which I want to cut (5 cylinders) **after cutting always sticks on the shape** that I want to cut (after choosing difference). Tried flipping normals and triangulation modifier on all shapes. But nothing helps! Begging for some wise words!

[image: I should use difference, but it acts partly as union.]
[image]

Comment: have you given a bit of thickness to your plate? I guess it will work if you do, use the Solidify modifier, apply it, then try again boolean

Comment: Nice, it worked! Thanks a lot, moonboots !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *Solidify* modifier to give thickness to your plate, apply it, then try again. Boolean needs thickness. If you don't want to give thickness to your object, use the *Knife Project* tool.